# kubernetes ServiceAccount Role Verification failed

Tags: kubernetes

questions:

Create a service account name dev-sa in default namespace, dev-sa can create below components in dev namespace:

Deployment
StatefulSet
DaemonSet

result:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dev-sa
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: sa-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["deployment","statefulset","daemonset"]
  verbs: ["create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: sa-rolebinding
  namespace: dev
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dev-sa
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: sa-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Validation:

```
kubectl auth can-i create deployment -n dev \
--as=system:serviceaccount:default:dev-sa
no
```

This is an exam question, but I can't pass

Can you tell me where the mistake is? thx

Answer (score 0):

First, the `apiGroups` of `Deployment`, `daemonSet`, and `statefulSet` is `apps`, not `core`. So, for the `apiGroup`s value, instead of `""`, put `"apps"`. (an empty string representing `core`)

Second, remember: `resources` always define in **Plural** of "**kind**". So, for `resources` values, you always should use **plural** names. e.g. instead of `deployment`, you use `deployments`

So, your file should be something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dev-sa
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: sa-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments","statefulsets","daemonsets"]
  verbs: ["create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: sa-rolebinding
  namespace: dev
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dev-sa
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: sa-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

For `apiGroups`'s values, be sure to check [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/)

---

I suggest you read [this article](https://github.com/alifiroozi80/CKA/tree/main/CKA#users--permissions) about Users and Permissions in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

in Role, use `*` on api group, and add `s` on resource name.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: dev-sa
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: sa-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["deployments", "statefulsets", "daemonsets"]
  verbs: ["create"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: sa-rolebinding
  namespace: dev
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dev-sa
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: sa-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```